# Expandable listview onItemLongClick and getChildView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, onlongclicklistener

Good day!

I want to make the *setItemChecked* on the **getChildView** to have the original position i used in the *onItemLongClick* what should i used for that to have a correct position to be used in this statement ***mExpandableListView.isItemChecked(childPosition)*** or is there any approach that i could used to have a correct position.
NOTE: i already used the 
***int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);*** and the position was incorrect when it uses in **getChildView**

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // validate if item selected is a child not the groupview
    if (!mIsMultiSelection) {
        mIsMultiSelection = true;
        int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);
        mExpandableListView.setItemChecked(position , true);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (mExpandableListView.isItemChecked(childPosition)) {
        Log.e("test2"," " + childPosition);
    }
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your question properly. Do you need to enable "Multi check" in ExpandableListView. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it would be a multi validation for isItemChecked, but the position was incorrect when it goes in getChildView so if possible is their anyway to get the position that was set to true on setItemChecked?

Comment: Is there any specific id with the child object that you can hold. So whenever your item is checked mark it in a map or set and then when it is rendered check the item is checked or not. With this approach it will be easy for you to handle the selected items logic. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved my problem, in order to get the original position in the **getChildView** first get the packPosition which is the raw position for the expandable listview, then used it to **getFlatListPosition** see my snippet below

```
long packPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    int rawPosition = mExpandableListView.getFlatListPosition(packPosition);
```

I hope it will help you guys!